# jquery datepicker on dynamic input fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need help with datepicker on dynamic created input fields...

I have this form:

```
    <table id="reminder">
                 <tr>
                 <th>Payment Reminders</th> 
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><label>Reminder</label></td>                              
                    <td><input type="text" name="payreminder[]" id="payreminder" class="input1" size="20" ><script>$('#payreminder').datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2011:2020'}); </script></td> 
                    <td><label>Description</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="input1" name="paydescription[]" id="paydescription"></td>
                    <td> <a href="#" onClick="addReminder('dynamicInputReminder');" title="Add another">Add another</a></td>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td colspan="6"><div id="dynamicInputReminder"></div> </td> 

                </tr>


        </table>
```

And the javascript for adding more reminders is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

 var counterReminder = 1;
 var limit = 20;              
  function addReminder(divName){ 
     if (counterReminder == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counterReminder+ " inputs");
      }
      else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<td><label>Reminder</label></td><td><input type=\"text\"  id=\"payreminder["+counterReminder+"]\" name=\"payreminder["+counterReminder+"]\" class=\"input1\" ></td><td><label>Description</label></td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"paydescription["+counterReminder+"]\" name=\"paydescription["+counterReminder+"]\" class=\"input1\"></td>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      counterReminder++;
 } 
}
</script>
```

The question is: How and where can I call the script bellow for the date picker so that it works for the dynamically created fields ?

```
<script>$('#payreminder').datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2011:2020'}); </script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a class instead of an id for your input field, for example

```
<input type=\"text\"  id=\"payreminder["+counterReminder+"]\" name=\"payreminder["+counterReminder+"]\" class=\"payreminder\" >

<script>
    $(document).on('focusin', '.payreminder', function(){
      $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2011:2020'});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

remove your script and put this at the end of the code.

**NOTE: id should always be unique so i used class here.**

change you ids to class "payreminder".

```
$(document).find('.payreminder').datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2011:2020'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

 var counterReminder = 1;
 var limit = 20;              
 function addReminder(divName) { 
     if (counterReminder == limit)  {
         alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counterReminder+ " inputs");
     } else {
         var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
         newdiv.innerHTML = "<td><label>Reminder</label></td><td><input type=\"text\"  id=\"payreminder["+counterReminder+"]\" name=\"payreminder["+counterReminder+"]\" class=\"input1\" ></td><td><label>Description</label></td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"paydescription["+counterReminder+"]\" name=\"paydescription["+counterReminder+"]\" class=\"input1\"></td>";
         document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
         $(newDiv).find('input').datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C, changeMonth: true, changeYear:  true, yearRange: '2011:2020'});
         counterReminder++;
     } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try exactly what I wrote? Because I made some changes to your last code snippet.

Comment: Yes I have made copy-paste on the whole script

Comment: Sorry this still doesn't work. However thank you for traying to help. I have already accepted the answer of @Alfred Bez

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('focusin', 'input[id^=payreminder]', function(){
  $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2011:2020'});
});
```

Comment: That id selector wont work. He adds a counter at the end, because there will be more than one picker. Try this instead: `'input[id^=payreminder]'`

Answer (score 0):

add a class named date on each input field on which you want to add datepicker, 
Now each time you add new field, call following function

```
$(".date").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a `data-` attribute for each input instead of a class. The following initializes any datepicker `<input type="text" data-datepicker ...>` tags as soon as the page is loaded, and then can be called again after the new reminder is added.

```
function initDatePicker () {
    $("input[data-datepicker]").datepicker();
};
$(document).ready(initDatePicker());
```

Additionally, I've found it to be useful to call the destroy() method for all the datepicker `<input>`'s each time you reinitialize them; otherwise, they seem to break. I used something like the following:

```
function addReminder(divName){
    ...
    $("input[data-datepicker]").datepicker('destroy');
    initDatePicker();
    ...
};
```

Obviously, make sure you call `datepicker('destroy')` *before* you call `initDatePicker()`, or you'll wipe out all your datepickers every time you add a new reminder.

[jQueryUI datepicker destroy method](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy)